# Inverse of exponential function

Tags: inverse

How can I find the inverse of $3^{5^{x}}$ ? I tried using logarithm in base 3: $3^{5^{y}}=x \Longrightarrow \log_3x=5^y \Longrightarrow \log_5(\log_3x)=y$? Is it correct? in my book it says its another answer from those given so I can't know the correct one.Answers in my book are:

a)$\log_{243}x \quad x \in(0,\infty)$

b)$\log_{15}x$

c)$\log_{243}x \quad x \in(1,\infty)$

Comment: What does the book say the answer is?  Or does it just say "none of the above"?

Comment: none of the answers above

Comment: What are the other choices?

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: See the side note in my answer.  If the problem really says $3^{5^x}$ and not $(3^5)^x$ then there's some unfortunate ambiguity here.  Probably best to clarify with your instructor or at least see if your book has an explanation somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1:  Write $y = 3^{5^x}$.

Step 2:  Swap $x$ and $y$ to get $x = 3^{5^y}$.

Step 3:  Solve for $y$.
\begin{align*}
  x &= 3^{5^y}\\
  \log_3 x &= \log_3 \left(3^{5^y}\right)\\
  \log_3 x &= 5^y\\
  \log_5 (\log_3 x) &= \log_5 (5^y)\\
  \log_5 (\log_3 x) &= y
\end{align*}
So it looks like the answer is indeed $y = \log_5(\log_3 x)$.

Note that as another answerer pointed out, one of the choices may be this answer in a different form.

---

Side note:  Some people may argue that the original function can be interpreted as $y = 3^{5^x} = (3^5)^x = 243^x$.  I disagree with this because I interpret $3^{5^x}$ without parentheses as meaning $3^{(5^x)}$, which I believe more closely conforms to order of operations.

Comment: Though you disagree, this is clearly what the problem statement means. Indeed the three proposals are of the form $\log_nx$, so that the original function is a simple exponential $n^x$. I'd be curious to see the typesetting in the book.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are multiple possible ways to *express* the answer to this problem. If
$$y=3^{5^x}$$
then you could solve for $x$ your way, by using $\log_3$ and $\log_5$ to get
$$x=\log_5 \log_3 x$$
or you could use the natural logarithm (which is what I suspect your book did):
$$y=3^{5^x}$$
$$\ln y=\ln 3^{5^x}$$
$$\ln y=5^x\ln 3$$
$$\ln \ln y=\ln(5^x\ln 3)$$
$$\ln \ln y=\ln5^x+\ln \ln 3$$
$$\ln \ln y-\ln \ln 3=x\ln5$$
$$x=\frac{\ln \ln y-\ln \ln 3}{\ln 5}$$
Is this close to what your book had?

The book may also have chosen to deviate from this process at this step:
$$\ln y=5^x\ln 3$$
and instead divide both sides by $\ln 3$ to get
$$\frac{\ln y}{\ln 3}=5^x$$
$$\ln \frac{\ln y}{\ln 3}=\ln 5^x$$
$$\ln \frac{\ln y}{\ln 3}=x\ln 5$$
$$x=\frac{1}{\ln 5}\ln \frac{\ln y}{\ln 3}=$$
Again, all of these answers are equivalent, you yours is still correct.